# grid: specify only the number of col/row occupied by the fillers

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to fill a container div with a grid-template css style of 9 row and 9 column with a lot of various smaller div, with each a different number of occuped column and row, but without specified the starting row or column  (I don't know/don't care where they land, I just want to fill the container div as much as I can

How do I do it ?

my code:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 15px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 15px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div grid-width=3 grid-height=4></div>
  <div grid-width=2 grid-height=2></div>
  <div grid-width=1 grid-height=1></div>
  <div grid-width=3 grid-height=4></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to consider `span`

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 15px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 15px);
  grid-gap:5px;
  border:1px solid;
}
.container > * {
  background:red;
  grid-row:span var(--grid-height,1);
  grid-column:span var(--grid-width,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="--grid-width:3;--grid-height:4"></div>
  <div style="--grid-width:2;--grid-height:2"></div>
  <div style="--grid-width:1;--grid-height:1"></div>
  <div style="--grid-width:3;--grid-height:4"></div>
  <div style="--grid-width:1;--grid-height:1"></div>
  <div style="--grid-width:1;--grid-height:4"></div>
  <div style="--grid-width:5;--grid-height:1"></div>
</div>
```